# Play 2.5: Form validation - on error, value of form is "Optional.empty"

Tags: java, forms, validation, playframework

I am developing an application with Play 2.5. Models and Form data are separate classes, so I have a class "Page" and "PageForm".

In PageForm is a method "validate()" which returns null if there was no error or a List if the validation failed:

```
public List<ValidationError> validate() {
    List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    Page checkForDuplicatePage = PageRepository.getInstance().getByName(name);

    if(checkForDuplicatePage != null && checkForDuplicatePage.id != id) {
        errors.add(new ValidationError("name", "The name is already in use by another page"));
    }

    // ...

    return errors.isEmpty() ? null : errors;
}
```

In my controller I call:

```
Form<PageForm> form = formFactory(PageForm.class).bindFromRequest();
```

This works really well if the data in the form is correct. However, if validate() finds an error (and it really doesn't matter what kind, even a `return new ArrayList<>()` triggers this), the "value" attribute of my form is Optional.empty. The "data" attribute actually has all the data passed to the form.

This means I can't use the form to pass it to my view, which should display the data with error messages. Instead I get a `[CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present]`. Sometimes (I haven't figured out why that happens yet) it also says `[CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get]`.

I compared my code with other projects and the official docs, but they all seem to be doing what I have here.

Answer (score 0):

I use Scala Play rather than Java, so YMMV. But to me, I don't think that `validate` should return `null` at all. It should return the empty `ArrayList` if there are no errors. I suspect that this will eliminate the `None.get` error message. I'm not sure how much I can help, though, because I don't really understand very well what your code is intended to do. For example, the sentence

> However, if validate() finds an error (and it really doesn't matter what kind, even a return new ArrayList<>() triggers this)

seems kind of ambiguous to me. Where is the `return new ArrayList<>()` call that triggers the error?